# jQuery iterating through inputs not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, input

I have a HTML div (`f`) with `input`s in, and I would like it to be that when the input is clicked off, it changes to the `bad_input` class that I have specified (background color is red). However, this does not work and I am unsure of how to fix it. The inputs have `placeholder` tags, however, I am sure this is not the reason why it is not working.

```
$("#f input").blur(function()
    {
    if (!$(this).val())
        {
        $(this).attr('class', 'bad_input');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/rqxcpmr6/

Comment: Did you put your code in the `$(document).ready()` handler? Are you adding inputs dynamically? If so, you need to use event delegation.

Comment: Font color won't do anything if the input field is empty. Try using background color, like in my fiddle.

Comment: @Barmar - I meant background color anyway, amended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User `.addClass()` jquery method to add the class, not `attr()`

What you are doing will add a attribute with `class = "bad_input"` in the input

```
        $("#f input").blur(function()
            {
            if (!$(this).val())
                {
                  $(this).addClass('bad_input');
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#f input").blur(function(){
    if (!$(this).val()){
        $(this).addClass('bad_input').focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#f input").blur(function()
    {
    if ($(this).val()=="")
        {
        $(this).addClass('bad_input');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't actually see anything wrong with your code there. I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dashood/njjewzm2/) that shows it working and tweaked the jQuery a little bit, similar to how others have.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#f input").on("blur", function() {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            $(this).addClass("bad_input");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("bad_input");
        }
    });
});
```

Are you loading the elements dynamically though Ajax or something similar? When you use $("el").blur the event is bound on document ready so if the markup containing the elements is injected after document ready, the event will not be bound. Using $("el").on("blur") helps with this.

Also, try adding an alert to your code to ensure the event is firing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it...

The inputs already were in a defined class (`"#f input"`) in a css file, and to fix it, I had to add the `!important` tag in my css file for `'bad_input'`.